# mount: Invalid argument

Tags: android, adb, mount, fs

I get the following error when trying to push ,can anyone provide inputs on how to debug this?

```
C:\Users\>adb shell mount -o rw,remount /new_firmware /new_firmware
mount: Invalid argument
```

Comment: do just `mount -o rw,remount /new_firmware`

Comment: @AlexP. - thats gives a syntax error as follows  Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type] device directory

Comment: the remount command using `mount` applet from the standard android `toolbox` is exactly as I wrote above. the error you get is suggesting that `/new_firmware` is not an existing mount point.

Comment: Totally the same problem, OTA update fixed it